# sensitivity analysis

Tags: r

I have a data frame as shown below
let's call this as DF1

[image: df1]

and I need to generate a new data frame as shown below

let's call this df2

[image: DF2]

df2 is nothing but, repetition of other columns except the first column A in df1

df1[1,1] is 1. so, I need to generate three rows in df2 which don't include 1 keeping the values of other columns constant correspondingly.

similarly, df1[2,1] is 2. so, I need to three rows in df2 which don't include 2 but the other three between 1 thru 4 keeping the values of other columns constant correspondingly.

please help me in doing this

thanks in advance

Comment: Why do you repeat three times?

Answer (score 2):

Here is an idea via base R,

```
d2 <- df[rep(rownames(df), each = 3), ]
d2$A <- unlist(lapply(df$A, function(i) setdiff(seq(4), i)))
```

which gives,

> ```
>     A B C D
> 1   2 2 3 4
> 1.1 3 2 3 4
> 1.2 4 2 3 4
> 2   1 1 2 3
> 2.1 3 1 2 3
> 2.2 4 1 2 3
> 3   1 3 4 2
> 3.1 3 3 4 2
> 3.2 4 3 4 2
> 4   1 2 3 4
> 4.1 2 2 3 4
> 4.2 3 2 3 4
> ```

**NOTE:** You can get rid of rownames with `rownames(d2) <- NULL`

Comment: similar approach with `data.table` `setDT(df1)[rep(seq_len(.N), each = 3)][, A := setdiff(as.numeric(1:4), A[1]), A][]`

Comment: for(c in c(1:4)){
  for(r in nrow(df) : 1){
    z = (1:4)[-df[r,c]]
    for(p in z){
      tr_temp[r,c] = p
      if(r == nrow(df)){
        out =   data.frame(tr_temp)
      }
      else{
        out = data.frame(out,tr_temp)
      }
    }
  }
}

I have been trying to use the above approach. so, as to dynamically apply the same logic for remaining columns as well but I am unable to 

pls help
thanks in advance